# How to store query result in a variable in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, store

I am using following query:

```
DECLARE 
result varchar2(100);

BEGIN
select (systimestamp - (select date_time from test where id=2945134)) into result from dual;

SELECT SUBSTR(result, 3,1) Final_result
FROM DUAL;

END;
```

It is showing an error like:

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

I need to store result value from first query into result variable and then use that result variable to show the `substring (3,1)` as a Final_result.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with that? (Implicitly) Converting an `interval` value to a string seems like a *very* strange thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE 
  result varchar2(100);
BEGIN

  select substr((systimestamp - (select date_time from test where id=2945134)), 3,1)
    into result
  from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line(result);
END;
/
```

But this is a highly dubious thing you are doing. You are relying on implicit datatype conversion (`interval` --> `varchar`) which will not work properly if your NLS settings change.

You would better use `to_char()` to format the resulting `interval` to something appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of making 2 select from the same table, just 1 should suffice.
Also as a practice, always try using the fully qualified name of your objects

Why do you need the "DUAL" table

```
DECLARE 
@final_result varchar2(100);

BEGIN
select @final_result= SUBSTR((systimestamp - (select date_time from test where id=2945134)),3,1);

END;
```

Comment: That is not valid for Oracle